# Sql Server - Working with large table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a table with about one million records inside. Currently it has grown upto 2GB. I need to partition this table or any other method to make this table less size.

What I meant by partitioning is breaking the table into TableName_1, TableName_2 when size is growing & combining them at the data retrieval

Is there any way to perform this?

Comment: _"table with about one million records"_ is not _large_. Do you mean _billion_ instead?

Comment: That's tiny in data sizes.  You're optimising the wrong thing, how about you post the problem not the perceived solution?

Comment: You need to partition a table in SQL Server? Perhaps you could do some research on this exact topic and post a specific problem. For example have a think about which is the best column to partition on.

Comment: Note that SQL Server table partitioning requires Enterprise Edition.  Although partitioning can improve manageability of large tables, it will not magically improve performance.  The key to performance is query and index tuning regardless of table size.

Comment: Table size can be reduced with page or row compression (also and Enterprise Edition feature).

Answer (score 2):

First off, 1 million rows is really not that much, nor is 2 GB worth of a table.

To answer your question, though, yes, [table partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx) is fully supported in SQL Server.

You could for instance, partition between historic and "recent" or "active" data based on a date field. Alternatively, you could partition using geographical segmentation and thus spread the data based on a country field.(Both examples of horizontal partitioning).

Alternatively, you can do a vertical partition where you cut the table into different amounts of columns (which could be useful in case your table contains a number of columns that are rarely used).

More info: [MSDN - Table Partitioning (explains horizontal and vertical partitioning)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178148()

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions that you have a large table and you need to partition it is incorrect.

You need to optimize your queries and to index your fields. Also, if you have frequently used data then it might be a good idea to create a table for cached values.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented one such solution and **blogged** about it long ago. That has a very detailed explanation with diagrams. Hope that would help you.

http://dattatraynale.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/sql-server-partitioning-design-4.html